# SubQuery returning Multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have got Two Tables

Product (Id, Name, CCode)

Category (CCode, CatName)     - No Primary Key

> Insert Into ProductNew (DW_Prod_Id, ProdId, ProdName, CC, CName)
>
> Select Dw_Prod_Id.Nextval, Id, Name, CCode,
>
> ```
>     (Select CatName
>      From Category cc, Product p
>      Where  cc.CCode IN p.CatCode
>      Group By CatName )
> ```
>
> From  Product;

*SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"*

I am getting the above error Because my SubQuery returns more than one row.
I would like to Match the CatCode of each row from Product table to the Category Table so that I can obtain the CatName and then Insert rows into my New Table :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if product can have only one category :

```
INSERT INTO ProdcutNew (DW_Prod_Id, ProdId, ProdName, CC, CName)

(SELECT Dw_Prod_Id.Nextval, p.Id, p.Name, cc.CCode, cc.CName
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Category cc on p.CatCode = cc.CCode)
```

And you can correct your table name

> ProdcutNew

to ProductNew ;)

**EDIT :**

But if, as @Gordon Linoff pointed, you have duplicates CCode, this won't work.

If you don't want a primary key on Category table, add at least a unique constraint (you'll have to clean your datas first)

```
ALTER TABLE Category ADD CONSTRAINT Unique_code UNIQUE(CCode);
```

**EDIT 2 :**

But the proper way would be :

Add an Id in Category as PK, and use it as Category_ID FK in Product (if CCode can change)
With the unique constraint on CCode.

Comment: Yup changed my table name and let me try this out ;)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have dulicates in your category table; otherwise a simple join would suffice:

```
select p.*, c.ccode
from Category c join
     Product p
     on c.ccode = p.catcode
```

To choose one category arbitrarily, do something like:

```
select p.*, c.ccode
from (select c.*
      from (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by c.ccode order by c.ccode) as seqnum
            from Category c
           ) c
       where seqnum = 1
      ) c join
     Product p
     on c.ccode = p.catcode
```

Comment: If I want to put Where rowid Not In (Select Source_RowId From A3_Error_Event Where Filter_Id = 1 ); I get an error - SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined